# Obtener IP de cliente desde PHP

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo obtener la direccion IP real del cliente desde `PHP` si fuera posible.

Esto quiere decir que haya conexión directa, o por medio de un `proxy`, o `router` o lo que fuere, siempre me identifique la `IP` real del computador cliente.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Te compartiré un script PHP que he creado investigando. Lo uso para saber las personas que acceden a una app Android que consulta datos en mi servidor a través de una URL.

El script muestra lo siguiente:

- IP del cliente
- Fecha
- País, Ciudad u otros datos geográficos del cliente, para ello consulta una API llamada Geoplugin. Con dicha API puedes determinar varios elementos geográficos del IP.
- Recurso al que ha accedido el cliente. En mi caso quería saber a qué parte de mi API se estaba accediendo. El script recupera ese dato y lo escribe en el archivo.
- Escribe los resultados en un archivo .txt .La salida de los resultados se puede adaptar a tu contexto, o sea, archivo, impresión en pantalla, envío por correo electrónico, etc. eso dependerá de lo que quieras hacer. En este caso concreto los datos son escritos en un archivo, una especie de log de visitas.

**Notas:**

- Este en un script con más opciones de las que estás pidiendo, si sólo quieres obtener el IP sin más, puedes ignorar las otras partes como el uso de Geoplugin, o la obtención de la URL, etc.
- [Geoplugin](http://www.geoplugin.com) es una API interesante *un recurso webmaster gratuito que proporciona con facilidad tecnología de geolocalización...*

  Sirve para localizar la IP y para otras cosas, la puedes probar en línea, en el enlace.

Bueno, ahora vamos con el script. He comentado algunas cosas, de forma que es muy fácil de entender:

**Código:**

```
<?php

    //Llamamos a la función, y ella hace todo :)
    write_visita ();

    //función que escribe la IP del cliente en un archivo de texto    
    function write_visita (){

        //Indicar ruta de archivo válida
        $archivo="ruta/archivo/visitas.txt";

        //Si que quiere ignorar la propia IP escribirla aquí, esto se podría automatizar
        $ip="mi.ip.";
        $new_ip=get_client_ip();

        if ($new_ip!==$ip){
            $now = new DateTime();

       //Distinguir el tipo de petición, 
       // tiene importancia en mi contexto pero no es obligatorio

        if (!$_GET) {
            $datos="*POST: ".$_POST;

        } 
        else
        {
            //Saber a qué URL se accede
            $peticion = explode('/', $_GET['PATH_INFO']);
            $datos=str_pad($peticion[0],10).' '.$peticion[1];   
        }
        $txt =  str_pad($new_ip,25). " ".
                str_pad($now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),25)." ".
                str_pad(ip_info($new_ip, "Country"),25)." ".json_encode($datos);

        $myfile = file_put_contents($archivo, $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }


    //Obtiene la IP del cliente
    function get_client_ip() {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
           $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        return $ipaddress;
    }


    //Obtiene la info de la IP del cliente desde geoplugin

    function ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location", $deep_detect = TRUE) {
        $output = NULL;
        if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
            $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            if ($deep_detect) {
                if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            }
        }
        $purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
        $support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
        $continents = array(
            "AF" => "Africa",
            "AN" => "Antarctica",
            "AS" => "Asia",
            "EU" => "Europe",
            "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
            "NA" => "North America",
            "SA" => "South America"
        );
        if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support)) {
            $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
            if (@strlen(trim($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode)) == 2) {
                switch ($purpose) {
                    case "location":
                        $output = array(
                            "city"           => @$ipdat->geoplugin_city,
                            "state"          => @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName,
                            "country"        => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName,
                            "country_code"   => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode,
                            "continent"      => @$continents[strtoupper($ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode)],
                            "continent_code" => @$ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode
                        );
                        break;
                    case "address":
                        $address = array($ipdat->geoplugin_countryName);
                        if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_regionName) >= 1)
                            $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                        if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_city) >= 1)
                            $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                        $output = implode(", ", array_reverse($address));
                        break;
                    case "city":
                        $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                        break;
                    case "state":
                        $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                        break;
                    case "region":
                        $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                        break;
                    case "country":
                        $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;
                        break;
                    case "countrycode":
                        $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }

?>
```

---

**Resultado**

Parte de los datos escritos en el archivo:

```
82.24.244.140             2017-05-02 03:43:10       United Kingdom            "laudes     20170502"
89.141.58.49              2017-05-02 04:03:38       Spain                     "oficio     20170502"
80.58.131.161             2017-05-02 05:37:46       Spain                     "oficio     20170502"
186.119.11.69             2017-05-02 06:00:42       Colombia                  "laudes     20170502"
186.119.11.69             2017-05-02 06:03:17       Colombia                  "visperas   20170502"
137.101.114.197           2017-05-02 06:30:34       Spain                     "tercia     20170502"
189.163.204.25            2017-05-02 07:00:40       Mexico                    "homilias   20170502"
179.40.81.2               2017-05-02 07:06:03       Argentina                 "oficio     20170502"
176.83.200.79             2017-05-02 07:23:57       Spain                     "laudes     20170502"
190.102.58.34             2017-05-02 07:45:20       Panama                    "homilias   20170502"
170.51.58.170             2017-05-02 08:00:28       Paraguay                  "tercia     20170502"
187.134.245.128           2017-05-02 08:42:29       Mexico                    "laudes     20170502"
83.32.169.72              2017-05-02 11:48:40       Spain                     "visperas   20170502"
```

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano, muy completa tu respuesta! y pasa a través del proxy sin problemas

Comment: @JoséMiguelSepulveda Gracias, me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.

Comment: ADVERTENCIA DE SEGURIDAD: Esta pieza de código es propensa a IP Spoofing, debe tenerse especial cuidado en qué lugar del desarrollo se incluye.

Comment: Donde esta la solucion que implementa LDAP; cerraste esta otra pregunta [Q](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/558533/c%c3%b3mo-tratar-ajax-dentro-de-un-mismo-archivo-php-para-mostrar-ip-de-un-equipo) sobre LDAP apuntando que aqui tenias la respuesta y no veo la implementacion de LDAP.

Answer (score 9):

Los códigos dados en las respuestas son vulnerables a la *falsificación* (spoofing) y tienes que tener cuidado donde lo uses.

En simple palabras:

> Obtener la dirección IP **real** de un *cliente/usuario* **nunca** será fiable.

---

En las respuestas se encuentra varios encabezados (`HTTP_`) cuales no se sabe si están establecidos por diferentes [proxies](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor_proxy) y el problema es que con los encabezados `HTTP` pueden ser manipulados fácilmente:

- [curl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl): `curl --header "X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.0.2" http://example.com`
- Extensión para Chrome: [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj)

Es decir, por seguridad (*ej. en el entorno de autenticaciones o similar*), no se **debería** utilizarse  ninguno de esos valores, ya que el *cliente/usuario* puede modificar el encabezado `X_FORWARDED_FOR` o `CLIENT_IP` a cualquier valor, al menos que tengas un [proxy inverso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor_proxy#Proxy_inverso_.28Reverse_Proxy.29) de confianza.

Y de todas maneras se debería validar las entradas del *cliente/usuario* ya que puede incluir sentencias peligrosas en el encabezado `HTTP`, ej.: `'; DROP TABLE users;--`

---

No estando detrás de un proxy:

`REMOTE_ADDR` te dará una IP *real*, la cual sera la más confiable que puedes obtener, siendo la IP de origen de la conexión [TCP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_de_control_de_transmisi%C3%B3n) y no puede sustituirse cambiando una cabecera `HTTP`.

---

Sabiendo todo esto y teniendo las precauciones puedes obtener la IP de la siguiente forma:

```
function getUserIpAddress() {

    foreach ( [ 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR' ] as $key ) {

        // Comprobamos si existe la clave solicitada en el array de la variable $_SERVER 
        if ( array_key_exists( $key, $_SERVER ) ) {

            // Eliminamos los espacios blancos del inicio y final para cada clave que existe en la variable $_SERVER 
            foreach ( array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $_SERVER[ $key ] ) ) as $ip ) {

                // Filtramos* la variable y retorna el primero que pase el filtro
                if ( filter_var( $ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE ) !== false ) {
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return '?'; // Retornamos '?' si no hay ninguna IP o no pase el filtro
}
```

***** Usamos la función [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php) para filtrar los valores con las siguientes indicaciones:

- `FILTER_VALIDATE_IP`

  > Valida si es valor es una dirección IP, sea **IPv4** o **IPv6**.
- `FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE`:

  > Falla si se intenta validar alguna de los siguientes rangos privados
  >   de IPv4: 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 y 192.168.0.0/16.
  >
  > Falla si se intenta validad direcciones IPv6 que empiecen por FD o FC.
- `FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE`:

  > Falla si se intenta validad alguno de los siguientes rangos IPv4
  >   reservados: 0.0.0.0/8, 169.254.0.0/16, 192.0.2.0/24 y 224.0.0.0/4. ( tipos localhost/127.0.0.1 )
  >
  > Este flag no se aplica a direcciones IPv6.

Fuentes:

- [What is the most accurate way to retrieve a user's correct IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php)
- [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)
- [$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] gives server IP rather than visitor IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262081/serverremote-addr-gives-server-ip-rather-than-visitor-ip)
- [Sending CURL request with custom IP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167082)
- [Filtros de validación](http://php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.validate.php)
- [Opciones de filtrado](http://php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.flags.php)

Comment: Excelente respuesta, contempla cuestiones de seguridad que ninguna de las otras siquiera analiza. +1

Answer (score 4):

Conforme a tu pregunta, prueba con este método. Espero que te sirva.

```
<?php

    function getRealIP(){

        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])){

            return $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];

        }elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])){

            return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        }elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"])){

            return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];

        }elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"])){

            return $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        }elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"])){

            return $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"];

        }else{

            return $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

        }
    }       
?>
```

Comment: Estuve revisando el código, y funciona a través de proxy

Comment: ADVERTENCIA DE SEGURIDAD: Esta pieza de código es propensa a IP Spoofing, además no valida que el resultado sean IP's válidas, debe tenerse especial cuidado en qué lugar del desarrollo se incluye.