# ¿Obtener IP de los que ingresan a mi Página?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy iniciando con esto de PHP y acabo de subir un programita que me permite ingresar un usuario y una contraseña, registra correctamente, pero también use estos método de PHP para poder obtener el host y la ip de la máquina.

```
$pcName = gethostname(); // Obtengo el nombre
$pcIP = gethostbyname($pcName); // Obtengo la IP
```

Pero esto solo me captura la ip y el host del servidor donde se encuentra alojado el programa, pensé que lo haría desde donde uno se conecta.
Puedo lograr esto?, ingresar a mi "link" desde cualquier lugar y poder capturar la IP y el HOST de quien se loguea.
Si es así, como puedo lograrlo.

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67370/obtener-ip-de-cliente-desde-php

Comment: hola, sería genial si indicas que harías con ese dato solo mostrarlo o guardarlo en la base de datos

Comment: Alfredo Paz, solo es para almacenar en mi BD.
Ok, revisaré esos enlaces.