# ¿Cuál opción es mejor para obtener ip publica? y como escribo varios comandos en una linea

Tags: php

Quisiera saber cual es la mejor manera de obtener una ip publica, si usando la variable $`_SERVER` o por `CMD` usando `shell_exec`, es que, me han comentado que `$_SERVER` suele ser muy engañoso.

También quisiera saber como escribo varios comandos de CMD en la misma linea de `shell_exec()`

Comment: a que te refieres con "engañoso"?

Comment: que la ip puede ser cambiado con un proxy, y no sé si buscandolo con shell_exec me salga algo mas confiable

Comment: ya lo haz utilizado? me queda la duda por que veras que dentro de la comunidad sale quien o quienes sepan apoyarte; pero lo mas importante es que haz tratado

Comment: si, he usado shell_exec pero nada mas ejecutando 1 comando

Comment: [Mira esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/67640/29967), basada en una API, que te trae no solamente la dirección IP, sino también otros datos, como el país, la provincia, la ciudad, etc. En cuanto a la otra pregunta, pues eso, es otra pregunta, deberías plantearla aparte, pues son dos cosas muy distintas y este sitio funciona por preguntas.