# Validar una IP obtenida usando PHP

Tags: php, ip

Gracias a la [respuesta de A.Cedano en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/67640/68558), he encontrado una forma de **obtener la IP en mi sitio web usando PHP**. Pero he buscado más información y me he dado cuenta de que en algunas ocasiones estos valores **podrían ser cambiados por casi cualquier usuario** (Sin VPN, proxy, ni otras historias), y me gustaría saber **la  mejor forma de validarlos** (en el sentido de saber si tienen el formato correcto).

Otra cosa que me dificulta esto, es que al parecer, se supone que algunas de ellas devuelven una IP más larga (IPv6) o devuelven varias, y quiero solo 1, la más fiable.

Esta es la función:

```
function get_client_ip() {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
           $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        return $ipaddress;
    }
```

Necesito recoger la IP de los usuarios porque cuando alguien va a iniciar sesión, comruebo cuántos fallos ha tenido (se reinicia cada 24 horas) y si estos son 2 o más, se muestra el captcha, si no, no.

Comment: ¿Leíste la [respuesta de @aldanux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/101342/29967) en la pregunta a la que haces referencia más arriba?

Comment: @A.Cedano Acaba de leerlo. Yo lo necesito para mostrar el captcha en los inicios de sesión solo cuando el usuario haya tenido 2 errores ese mismo día. ¿Crees que para eso funcionará? Lo hago para que los usuarios no tengan que usar el captcha todo el rato, pero tampoco quiero que los bots puedan saltarse este filtro simpre que quieran. Saludos

Comment: Como imaginarás, en este mundo no hay nada seguro, en internet menos, porque muchas cosas se nos escapan. Aunque ahora que leo tu comentario me pregunto ¿por qué razón dejas que los bots entren a tu sitio? Puedes usar herramientas como [`UA Blacklist`](https://perishablepress.com/2013-user-agent-blacklist/)  que impiden que los bots pululen por tu sitio. Ojo, esa lista  (aunque data de 2013) es la mejor que conozco, la uso desde hace años, pero recuerdo que tenía un error y bloqueaba al buscador de Google. No recuerdo cómo lo corregí, creo que está en un comentario mío en el sitio de ellos.

Comment: Vale, entonces probaré esa herramienta y por ahora, como no tengo problemas, no voy a usar captcha. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intenta asi:

```
<?php

function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = array();
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress["ip"] = explode(",",getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))[0];
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress["ip"] = explode(",",getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))[0];
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress["ip"] = explode(",",getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))[0];
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress["ip"] = explode(",",getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))[0];
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress["ip"] = explode(",",getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))[0];
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress["ip"] = explode(",",getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))[0];
    else
        $ipaddress["ip"] = 'UNKNOWN';

    $v6 = preg_match("/^[0-9a-f]{1,4}:([0-9a-f]{0,4}:){1,6}[0-9a-f]{1,4}$/", $ipaddress["ip"]);
    $v4 = preg_match("/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/", $ipaddress["ip"]);

    if ( $v6 != 0 )
        $ipaddress["type"] = "IPv6";
    elseif ( $v4 != 0 )
        $ipaddress["type"] = "IPv4";
    else
        $ipaddress["type"] = "unknown";

    return $ipaddress;
}

$ip = get_client_ip();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Your local IP addresses:</h4>
        <ul></ul>
        <h4>Your public IP addresses:</h4>
        <ul><li><?php echo $ip["ip"];?></li></ul>
        <h4>Your IPv6 addresses:</h4>
        <ul></ul>
        <h4>Your Type IP addresses:</h4>
        <ul><li><?php echo $ip["type"];?></li></ul>
<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
        <script>
            //get the IP addresses associated with an account
            function getIPs(callback){
                var ip_dups = {};
                //compatibility for firefox and chrome
                var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
                    || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
                    || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
                if(!RTCPeerConnection){
                    //NOTE: you need to have an iframe in the page right above the script tag
                    //
                    //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
                    //<script>...getIPs called in here...
                    //
                    var win = iframe.contentWindow;
                    RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
                        || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
                        || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                    useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                }
                //minimal requirements for data connection
                var mediaConstraints = {
                    optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
                };
                var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};
                //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
                var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);
                function handleCandidate(candidate){
                    //match just the IP address
                    var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
                    var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];
                    //remove duplicates
                    if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
                        callback(ip_addr);
                    ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
                }
                //listen for candidate events
                pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){
                    //skip non-candidate events
                    if(ice.candidate)
                        handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
                };
                //create a bogus data channel
                pc.createDataChannel("");
                //create an offer sdp
                pc.createOffer(function(result){
                    //trigger the stun server request
                    pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});
                }, function(){});
                //wait for a while to let everything done
                setTimeout(function(){
                    //read candidate info from local description
                    var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');
                    lines.forEach(function(line){
                        if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
                            handleCandidate(line);
                    });
                }, 1000);
            }
            //insert IP addresses into the page
            getIPs(function(ip){
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.textContent = ip;
                //local IPs
                if (ip.match(/^(192\.168\.|169\.254\.|10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01]))/))
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(li);
                //IPv6 addresses
                else if (ip.match(/^[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7}$/))
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[2].appendChild(li);
                //assume the rest are public IPs
                else
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[1].appendChild(li);
            });
        </script>



</body>
</html>
```