# Crear tabla en archivo de texto

Tags: php

Tengo una función con un bucle el cual genera unos strings para descargar en formato .Tsv en mi caso.La cosa es que me gustaría saber alguna manera de poder imprimir estos datos en el archivo de una manera ordenada y no como lo estoy haciendo yo.

Código

```
 $consulta = json_decode(json_encode($consulta), true); 
 $rows="";
 $count = count($consulta);
 $header="ID - Km - Parking - Peaje - Otros gastos";

 for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){ 


  $usuario = $consulta[$i];
  $elemento= implode(' | ', $usuario);


  $rows .=$elemento . "\n"; 

 } 

 $rows= $header."\n".$rows;

 return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($rows) { echo $rows; }, 'users.tsv');
```

Y este es el resultado desordenado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías usar [`str_pad`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php) para esto. Pero no entiendo mucho tu lógica, sobre todo el `for` y el `implode` dentro. Otra cosa, si ese `.tsv` va a ser leído posteriormente como un archivo separado por tabulación, al modificarlo arbitariamente podrás tener problemas en una lectura posterior en otro contexto y para otros usos. Lo advierto porque eso no queda claro en la pregunta. No se sabe si te interesa nada más que quede bonito o si ese archivo va a tener más usos en otros contextos en los que la apariencia no importa.

Comment: @A.Cedano simplemente necesito que se quede como si fuese en una tabla todo ordenado y  el .tvs es solo un archivo de muestra, no tiene ninguna otra función. El for por que lo que recogo es un array y necesito sacarle los elementos y el implode para convertir el array en string y poder añadirlo a la cadena $rows, el array $consulta en verdad es un array asociativo de clase sttdclass por eso su conversion a  json, para poder trabajar con el.

Comment: Puedes usar `str_pad`, por ejemplo: `$rows .=str_pad($elemento, 15) . "\n";` ahí le dará un espacio de 15  para cada elemento, de esos `15` PHP descuenta los caracteres que tenga cada dato. Si quieres más o menos espacio, cambias el `15`. Para los encabezados, puedes meterlos en un array y hacer lo mismo.  El resultado que ves en [esta respuesta (al final)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/67640/29967) es con  `str_pad`.

Comment: amigo esto me ayudo también pero cuando sustituyo tu código por el mio el registro siguiente de la array se me sube y no realiza el salto de línea donde coloco el "\n" en tu código

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu comentario. Como te dije antes, ese `for` para mi es confuso, con ese salto de línea. ¿Qué representa ahí `$elemento` realmente? Tampoco entiendo qué quieres decir con *el registro siguiente de la array se me sube*

Comment: OK, no me había fijado en el implode. Prueba esto: `$elemento= implode(' | ', printf ("%15s",$usuario));`  y todo lo demás como lo tenías al principio. Eso debería imprimirte cada dato con tabulación de 15.

Comment: perdona el último implode me da un error de array to string conversion

Comment: ¿Podrias mostrar un pequeño ejemplo de `var_dump($consulta);` para sugerirte algo más seguro?

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["Usuario: "]=> int(7) ["Km"]=> float(169.63) ["Peaje"]=> float(12.5) ["Aparcamiento"]=> int(0) ["Otros_gastos"]=> float(11.3) } [1]=> array(5) { ["Usuario: "]=> int(10) ["Km"]=> float(12.15) ["Peaje"]=> int(0) ["Aparcamiento"]=> float(8.2) ["Otros_gastos"]=> int(10) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a simplificar las cosas y a corregir algunos errores:

1. Crearemos un array con los encabezados. Observa bien tu array, porque en el código tenías los encabezados mal (primero va el `Peaje` y luego el `Parking` según el array).
2. Leeremos ese array para sacar los encabezados tabulados (podrías usar el mismo array consulta si lo quisieras, pero en ese caso no podrías personalizar encabezados como `ID` por ejemplo).
3. Para leer `$consulta` usaremos dos `foreach` anidados sin mayores complicaciones. Y usaremos `sprintf` para agregar tabulaciones.
4. Todo lo iremos recogiendo en una variable `$table`.

El código quedaría así:

```
$consulta = json_decode(json_encode($consulta), true); 

$headers=array("ID", "Km", "Peaje", "Parking", "Otros gastos");
$table="";
foreach ($headers as $row){
    $table.=sprintf("|%-10s",$row);
}
$table.="\n";

foreach ($consulta as $row){
    foreach ($row as $v){
         $table.=sprintf("|%-10s",$v);
    }
    $table.="\n";   #Me faltaba esto, MUY IMPORTANTE
}
echo $table;
```

Comment: Mañana sin falta le hecho un vistazo y te comento @A.Cedano que aquu en españa son ya las dos de la madrugada, muchisimas gracias por el compromiso que estas teniendo, mañana en levantarme te comento !:D

Comment: Me ha podido la curiosidad, esta todo funcionando a la mil maravillas me estudiare mañana tu código para entender como lo has hecho, gracias amigo!!!! :D